WeazyPrint links with href attribute are non clickable
I generate PDFs with weazyprint but the hypertext links where the href is different from the link text are not clickable in the generated PDF.
Example:
<a href="https://app.exemple.com/" target="_blank"> https://app.exemple.fr/ </a>

works well, while
<a href="https://app.exemple.com/" target="_blank"> exemple </a>

isn't clickable.
Has anyone ever encountered this problem?
